# Evaluate $\int_CF.ds$ where $F=(\frac{-y}{x^2+y^2},\frac{x}{x^2+y^2})$

Tags: calculus

Evaluate $\int_CF.ds$ where $F=(\frac{-y}{x^2+y^2},\frac{x}{x^2+y^2})$
 where $C$ is the curve joining the points $(1,0)$ and $(3,0)$ obtained from the parabolas $x=y^2+1$ and $y=(x-3)^2$

My problem:I do not understand the curve $C$.What is it?Is it just line segment or a curvilinear triangle the region bounded by two parabolas and the line segment of x-axis?

Also if it is triangle then my computations shows it is equal to zero by using the Green's theorem.Is it correct?

Answer (score 0):

My understanding is that it's not a closed region but a curve (so Green's theorem can't be used--but yes, if it was any closed region (not containing the origin) you would get $0$):[image]

In case you need a few more hints, it's not hard to see that $\mathbf{F}=\bigtriangledown f$ for some scalar field $f$--hence the $0$ with Green. By the fundamental theorem,
\begin{align*}
\int_{C}\mathbf{F}\cdot d\mathbf{r}&=\int_{C}\bigtriangledown f\cdot d\mathbf{r}\\
&=f(3,0)-f(1,0).
\end{align*}
My apologies if I over-answered.

Comment: Of course, it wouldn't matter (since $\mathbf{F}$ is conservative) whether we took the two curves or just the line segment lying on the $x$-axis.